# Unable to define relationship within ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I am trying to create an association between my attribute_set and attribute tables. Though ActiveRecord keeps displaying this error.

```
ArgumentError: You tried to define an association named attributes on the model AttributeSet, but this will conflict with a method attributes already defined by Active Record. Please choose a different association name.
```

Comment: The error should be self-explanatory. Try a different attribute name instead of `attributes`, since that's a reserved method name for ActiveRecord.

Comment: well that just kills my whole app. I should be able to use whatever table name I require

Comment: Why do you think it kills your whole app?

Comment: because the table naming is going to be all over the place now. its so much rework. if this was a standard php/sql app i can call the tables as i please, and this now means the last 3 hours of work has to be redone

Comment: I've been there before - it definitely sucks. Do a global find-and-replace and it shouldn't take too long hopefully :)

Comment: Rails uses 'convention over configuration' for, among other things, table names and references.  It's much less work to use those, rather than trying to force your own naming scheme on things.

Comment: im not trying to force my own naming scheme. i wanted a table called attributes how stupid that i cannot use it because apparently its reserved

Comment: http://www.rubymagic.org/posts/ruby-and-rails-reserved-words